# Django code changes don't reflect on production server

Tags: django, production-environment, production

I made so changes in one of my model-forms in my Django apps - I added new input fields for the user. I then tested the changes in my environment and everything works fine. I then committed and pushed the changes to remote repo. I pulled the changes on my production server which runs on AWS. I ran `pkill -f runserver` in terminal to restart the server, however the changes didn't take place. Only the changes regarding html tags were visible (new labels and etc...).
The changes that weren't present are the ones that come from the model-from: new input fields for the user - those were just missing completely from the template page.
What can be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

you need to restart gunicorn service every time you make changes to the code.
run `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`
Do it and changes will reflect.

Comment: I tried and got: Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found

Comment: did you deploy your django app using nginx and gunicorn ?

Comment: This is my first time doing this, I think I have nginx installed, so I guess I use nginx.

Comment: If you are want to setup you django app using nginx and gunicorn use following instructions  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: nginx is already setup in production, and it already has a running website,I just added new changes and those changes don't appear in the template .

Comment: I tried '$ sudo systemctl restart nginx' but I still don't see my changes in the template.

Comment: its because gunicorn service is not installed correctely. You need to pass Gunicorn a module by specifying the relative directory path to Django's wsgi.py file, which is the entry point to our application, using Python's module syntax. Follw the instructions in above link to reinstall your django app.

Comment: does the restart take time for it to reflect live? Or is it supposed to be instant?

Comment: gunicorn service name might be diffirent for some application. Please make sure to restart the right service. To get the right service, you may redirect to server configuration . e.g. in nginx, 
**proxy_pass http://unix:/run/test_django.sock;** test_django is your service so run the following command, **sudo systemctl restart test_django**

Answer (score 1):

After you push changes to the production server you also need to migrate the database changes. 
On your local repo (where you make your model changes) you run the `makemigrations` command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And after you fetch your changes on your production server you run the `migrate` command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I did that as well, but I still don't see the changes in the template

Comment: Do you have the possibility to check the tables in your production database to confirm that the migrations applied correctly? Because it sounds on your problem like the migration isn't done or failed somewhere.

Comment: No unfortunately i can't see the database. I need to point out though that the changes I did in the code were only on ModelForm and not on the model itself. In this case is the problem still about migrations?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it was changes in the model AND the form. No, in that case it won't be affected by migrations. Do you have any caches installed in your project?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure, this is my first time deploying. I think I have memcached installed though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server you're using : nginx, gunicorn, or apache..

If you setup the server using nginx and gunicorn , you could probably try restarting those services manually, but i'd recommend using something like supervisord to ease out the restart procedure..

If ur using apache, probably use

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: if I use nginx, will '$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart' work?

Answer (score 1):

If you use supervisor then you need to run

`sudo supervisorctl reload`

I was having the same problem, this command worked for me on AWS - Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Weird, I still have my running app not updated after several `sudo supervisorctl [reread]/[update]/[reload]/[restart all]`